# How to make a table with two tier headers in sonataAdmin?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.8

How to make a table with two-level headers with the use of sonataAdmin
like this :

[image]

```
protected static function getListField()
{
        'produced'     => array(
            null,
            array('template' => 'AdminBundle:Admin:totalProduced.html.twig'),
            'entity',
            array('class' => test::class,),
        ),
        'sold'     => array(
            null,
            array('template' => 'AdminBundle:Admin:total:Sold.html.twig'),
            'entity',
            array('class' => test::class,),
        ),
}
```

Now I can display a normal table with produced and these values + Sold and these values , So now I want to add a title ( Mars ) to my table

PS: Mars is just a title is not a variable and does not exist in datatable